# Error code -32999 while testing sample app at loadrunner

Tags: load-testing

I am beginner to hp load runner ,today i tested my first sample url(inbuilt url to test app) in hp loadrunner 9.0
i have done with recording and while i  playback the recording,i got stuck with an error message as seen in screen shot

[image: screenshot]

i tried with rerecording the application with `https/http` but the result is same,how can i rectify these type of errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't personally worked with HP-LR but had a friend who did and experienced the same error.

In his case, It was caused by the fact that he was making use of a variable.
"URL={URL}/where/he/wanted/to/test.html"

This was all nice and dandy but he never specified {URL}, And this caused the error in his case.

You should have a more clear indication of the error in the Err-Log.